# Issue related to Generics and Linq

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have got the list of Class Name as Follows:

```
Type[] typelist = typeof(Sample.Students).Assembly.GetTypes();
```

now i have complete list of all classes available in Sample NameSpace:

Now i want to get data  through class
I am using Devexpress Persistance class
so basically i have to create XPQuert Object as follows:

```
XPQuery<Employee> EmployeeQuery = new  XPQuery<Employees>(XPODefault.Session);
```

but in my case `Employee` class will be listed in `typelist` variable..
How can i create the object of XPQuery.. is it possible something like this:

```
XPQuery<typeof(typelist[0].Name)> EMployeeQuery = new XPQuery<typeof(typelist.Name)> (XPODefault.Session);
```

i meant i want to create object dynamically.. how can i do
Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public static IQueryable CreateQueryInstance(Type queryType) 
{
    var genericQueryTypeDefinition = typeof(XPQuery<>);
    var queryTypeArguments = new[] { typeof(queryType) };
    var genericQueryType = genericQueryTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType(queryTypeArguments);
    var queryObject = (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(genericQueryType, <your parameters here>);

    return queryObject;
}
```

And then use it as:

```
var myQueryObject = CreateQueryInstance(typelist[0]);
```

Of course you will NOT be able to have a nice XPQuery as you don't know the type at the compile time, but you still can have an IQueryable to start from.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,., but what kind of parameters i need to pass at the time of Creating Instance?

Comment: you need to pass an array of parameters you would actually be passing into the XPQuery<..> constructor. For example, your session: Activator.CreateInstance(genericQueryType, new object[] { XPODefault.Session });

Comment: If it is always the same parameter (XPODefault.Session) you can hardcode it there, otherwise I recommend you to have it as a parameter of CreateQueryInstance method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to dynamically construct a generic type.

```
Type queryType = typeof(XPQuery<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { typelist[0] };

Type constructed = queryType .MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
object myQuery = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, XPODefault.Session);
```

You need to use the [CreateInstance(type, params Object[] args)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) overload so you can specify the arguments needed for your constructor.

The only problem you have is that the returned type of `CreateInstance` is of type `object`. 
If you want to call any other methods on `myQuery`, you need to use reflection or the `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your reply: i am getting an exception at the time of creating an instance : "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani I've edited my answer and added a link to the correct overload for CreateInstance

Comment: HI.. I used to read the article and passed XPODefault.Session as Parameters- But still i am getting another Exception: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."